# Joomla 2.5.28 to 3.5.1 upgrade issue

Tags: joomla

working on upgrading my site from 2.5.28 to 3.4.1 and get the error

```
Duplicate entry '801' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=INSERT INTO `#__extensions` (`extension_id`, `name`, `type`, `element`, `folder`, `client_id`, `enabled`, `access`, `protected`, `manifest_cache`, `params`, `custom_data`, `system_data`, `checked_out`, `checked_out_time`, `ordering`, `state`) VALUES (801, 'weblinks', 'package', 'pkg_weblinks', '', 0, 1, 1, 0, '', '', '', '', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0);
```

think the url was something like install.finalise

when I reloaded the page I saw this error

```
1091 Can't DROP 'usertype'; check that column/key exists SQL=ALTER TABLE `#__users` DROP INDEX `usertype`;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: how did you upgraded? Manually or through control panel?

Answer (score 0):

[It appears this issue may be caused by excess SQL files from a previous upgrade (e.g. from Joomla 1.5, 1.6 or 1.7).](https://www.ostraining.com/support-forum/joomla-support/joomla-2-5-28-to-3-4-1-upgrade-issue/)

**Duplicate Entry**

Try reinstalling Weblinks which you can download from the JED at: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/official-extensions/weblinks

If this doesn't work you could try uninstalling and reinstalling Weblinks (but back up your website first in case your Weblinks data is deleted).

**Can't DROP 'usertype'**

This has already been answered at: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/4791/120